# Error handling not working on Selenium exception in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, error-handling

This is a part of my code:

```
import time
from xpath_info import *
from credentials import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager as gdm
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, WebDriverException

class NewtonClassroomAutomation:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = None

    def open_browser(self):

    # Newton Classroom link
        url ="https://griet.newtonclassroom.com/"

        # Installing gecko driver for opening firefox
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=gdm().install())

        # Opening the url
        self.driver.get(url)
        print("Browser is now opened successfully")
        time.sleep(3)

    def enter_credentials(self):
    
        # Clicking on the 'Sign In with Google' button
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(google_login_button).click()
        time.sleep(3)

        # Entering the email address
        try:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_text_box).send_keys(email)
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_button).click()
            print("Entered the email address")
            time.sleep(3)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            print("ERROR: The email address entered is either incorrect or does not exist.")

        # Entering the password
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_text_box).send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_button).click()
        print("Entered the password")
        time.sleep(3)
```

Even after adding the `except` clause, I am not getting the `print("ERROR: The email address entered is either incorrect or does not exist")` but I am getting the errors that selenium shows. I don't know why the error handling is not working in this case.

This is the error that my code is showing:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input
```

Error Stack Trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python Automation & Webscraping\Newton Classroom Automation\main.py", line 61, in <module>
    my_classroom_bot.enter_credentials()
  File "d:\Python Automation & Webscraping\Newton Classroom Automation\main.py", line 42, in enter_credentials
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_text_box).send_keys(password)
  File "C:\Users\ravur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\ravur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\ravur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ravur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input
```

Comment: It should work if the exception falls under `NoSuchElementException` btw what is your error stack trace ?

Comment: Please include the errors that selenium shows.

Comment: What error are thrown by Selenium that are not caught with your except?

Comment: @ewong I have added the error in the question

Comment: @Prophet NoSuchElementException

Comment: @cruisepandey I have added the stack trace in the question

Comment: Why would you use something like this `/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input` use relative path instead.

Comment: I see, thanks. Are you sure the indentation is correct there?

Comment: @cruisepandey I am still learning about the xpath and I don't know much about relative path.

Comment: @Prophet Yes, the indentations are correct.

Comment: @PraneethRavuri : please tell us which xpath variable represent `/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/span/section/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input`

Comment: @cruisepandey It represents the password input text box

Comment: Instead of `self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_text_box).send_keys(email)` use this `self.driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId').send_keys(email)` and see if it works

Comment: @cruisepandey I think the xpath is not relevant here. The issue is why the exception is not caught by the except block

Comment: @Prophet : Yes that's true, but we need to determine if try block is getting execute successfully or not, there's no print statement also :(..

Comment: @cruisepandey `self.driver.find_element_by_id('identifierId').send_keys(email)` is working

Comment: @PraneethRavuri : same way wrap it for password and have both (username and password) in a try block and then see if that still won't work ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I now know what is happening and I will change my code accordingly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error stack trace shows that the exception is occurring outside of the try block.
It shows that exception is in line 42, The following line is responsible for the exception.
`self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_text_box).send_keys(password)`

And this line is not in the try block. That is why you are getting the exception and not the handled message. Because the exception is not handled for this line.

You are using google login which detects selenium and prevents the login process to continue on the password page. That is why it most probably not finding the password page.

Form simple change do this:

```py
def enter_credentials(self):

    # Clicking on the 'Sign In with Google' button
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(google_login_button).click()
    time.sleep(3)

    # Entering the email address
    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_text_box).send_keys(email)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_button).click()
        print("Entered the email address")
        time.sleep(3)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("ERROR: The email address entered is either incorrect or does not exist.")

    # Entering the password
    try:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_text_box).send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(next_button).click()
        print("Entered the password")
        time.sleep(3)
    except NoSuchElementException:
    print("ERROR: The password field or the next button not found")
```

Edit:

To add explicit wait:

import:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

In the code use this

```py
 WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, email_text_box))).send_keys(email)
```

instead of

```py
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(email_text_box).send_keys(email)
```

Comment: Yes, now I understood what is happening and I will use explicit wait. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you tell me how can I implement explicit wait here?

Comment: @PraneethRavuri edited. check the code. Also check 
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html